# Unhandled WindowManagerBadTokenException when using datepicker control in Xamarin.Forms Content page

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to create an application using Xamarin.Forms. I have created a single content page and added a DatePicker Control over it.

The first time the activity is started, date picker work just fine ... however, whenwe close the application via mobile back button and relaunch the app it throws an un-handled exception on opening date picker saying this exception:

> ```
>     0x21 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal          C#
>        0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException  C#
>        0x26 in object.56027ba0-2dd5-40f3-bfa1-daf5399d2134     C#
>        0x63 in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/b5dc5ce9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:490,138            C#
>        0x4E in Android.App.Dialog.Show at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/b5dc5ce9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Dialog.cs:2497,5       C#
>        0x73 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.DatePickerRenderer.OnTextFieldClicked         C#
>        0xB in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.DatePickerRenderer.TextFieldClickHandler.OnClick    C#
>        0x13 in Android.Views.View.IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/b5dc5ce9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:1840,1223            C#
>        0x17 in object.56027ba0-2dd5-40f3-bfa1-daf5399d2134     C#
> ```

Comment: So, you are using the textview click event to launch the DatePicker dialog, Can you please show me some code so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using older Xamarin.Forms version it could be a bug: Take a look at possible fix: bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24773 (first comment)